# How to pass foreign key id as parameter while calling create form in rails 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My user interface needs to be such that a student record can be created:

1) by a student if he/she is over 18 years
OR
2) has to be created by parent if the student is <18 years.

In the student form, I have the Date of birth field, which I can use for that `isadult` validation, but I'm a little confused how to go about the logic above in general.

I am guessing it can be implemented as passing a `parent_id` parameter value to the `http://localhost:3000/student/new` form call. When the user indicates that he is an adult, the `parent_id` parameter value wont be included, otherwise, if the user is already logged in as a parent, then that `parent_id` would be passed to `http://localhost:3000/student/new?parent_id=1` (say).

Im struggling to understand how this is going to be implemented. Need some sample code for implementation. Please Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: If the user is logged as a parent you don't need any parent_id, you already have it, the id of the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

As Iceman suggests, you don't need to pass the parent_id as a parameter. In the controller's create, you can do something like

```
@student = Student.new(params)
@student.parent_id = @current_user.id if @current_user.isadult?
```

In the Student model you can add a validation that the current user is over 18 or has a parent id